# psycopg2 tests test_module AssertionError due to language?

Tags: python, centos7, psycopg2

I just installed a new postgresql server on a centos7, and I connect to it from another centos7 server. I ran psycopg2 tests.unittest.main to check this module. Everything is fine, except :

```
[myuser@myserver dbatools]$ python3 -c "from psycopg2 import tests; tests.unittest.main(defaultTest='tests.test_suite')" 
[...]
======================================================================
FAIL: test_diagnostics_values (psycopg2.tests.test_module.ExceptionsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/tests/test_module.py", line 189, in test_diagnostics_values
    self.assertEqual(e.diag.severity, 'ERROR')
AssertionError: 'ERREUR' != 'ERROR'
- ERREUR
?    ^^
+ ERROR
?    ^


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 641 tests in 27.328s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=62)
```

At first, both servers had LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 (Erreur = error in french ).
So I changed it to en_US.UTF-8 :

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Now I have :

```
[myuser@myserver dbatools]$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
       VC Keymap: fr
      X11 Layout: fr
[myuser@myserver dbatools]$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

The exception is raised here (psycopg2/tests/test_module.py) :

```
def test_diagnostics_values(self):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("select * from nonexist")
    except psycopg2.Error as exc:
        e = exc

    self.assertEqual(e.diag.sqlstate, '42P01')
    self.assertEqual(e.diag.severity, 'ERROR')
```

I had a look at the sources on github to find the definition of psycopg2.Error, but couldn't really find it.

In a python3 shell :

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> from psycopg2 import tests, __version__ as psycopg2_version
>>> print(psycopg2_version)
2.7.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
>>> tests.unittest.main(defaultTest='tests.test_suite')
#Same error
```

Has someone encounter this king of error running the tests of psycopg2 ? Why does it return a french word after I changed everything to en_US ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually it was indeed a language related error, but in postgresql server settings.

From http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#exceptions :

> exception psycopg2.Error
>
> diag
>
> ```
> A Diagnostics object containing further information about the error.
> ```

And from http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics :

> All the information available from the PQresultErrorField() function are exposed as attributes by the object, e.g. the severity attribute returns the PG_DIAG_SEVERITY code

So...

```
[myuser@mypostgresqlserver data]# grep fr_FR /data/postgresql.conf
lc_messages = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'                     # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'                      # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'                         # locale for time formatting
[myuser@mypostgresqlserver data]# vim /data/postgresql.conf
[myuser@mypostgresqlserver data]# grep lc_messages /data/postgresql.conf
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message
[myuser@mypostgresqlserver data]# systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service
```

Then :

```
[myuser@myserver dbatools]$ python3 -c "from psycopg2 import tests; tests.unittest.main(defaultTest='tests.test_suite')"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 641 tests in 24.979s

OK (skipped=62)
```